# Iptables multiple port redirects based on destination address

Tags: iptables, iptables-redirect

I have iptables setup for selective routing. In the current configuration 
it checks if the dst address is listed in a specific chain and if it is not it redirects the traffic to my proxy
port which is active on port 1080.

This works fine with the following setup:

```
iptables -t nat -N PROXY
# Do not redirect
iptables -t nat -A PROXY -d external.proxy.address.1 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A proxy -d external.proxy.address.2 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A PROXY -d 211.96.0.0/255.240.0.0 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A PROXY -d 211.128.0.0/255.128.0.0 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A PROXY -d 218.0.0.0/255.128.0.0 -j RETURN
... [and many more address] ...

# Redirect everything else to the proxy listening on port 1080
iptables -t nat -A PROXY -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1080
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -j PROXY
```

As mentioned this works fine for proxy1 but I am trying to redirect traffic in a similar way for destination 10.0.0.15 to a different proxy (proxy2) which listens on  port 1088.

I've tried several ways to accomplish this without success.

Configuration I have tried :

```
iptables -t nat -A PROXY -d 10.0.0.15 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1088 # didn't do anything
```

What would be the best way to achieve this (if it's possible)